# Redundant new lines in SNS messages in outlook

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, outlook, smtp

I met a weird behavior using sns-notification to my outlook mail box.
I set up an email-json notification. When sending a message I get the response below:

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "messageId",
  "TopicArn" : "topicArn",
  "Message" : "{\"eventId\": \"4e09c55e-c8c0-4482-b116-325e2c659fc8\", \"serviceServiceGG\": \"4d2bc58d-73fb-43b8-b98a-81d2b5b06599\", \"businessServiceName\": \"UUUU servicex transaction\", \"eventType\": \"FieldtoryServicetionCCCCCCC\", \"eventVersion\": \"2\", \"producedTimeStamp\": \"2020-12-01T10:36:37.868\", \"producedBy\": \"ServiceX Service\", \"producedByVersion\": \"0.2.0\", \"payload\": [{\"fieldxxxTransaction\": {\"commonTransactionProperties\": {\"transactionXX\": \"xxxx2739-c31a-41e8-9f76-c17d24ea5a14\", \"executed\": \"2020-12-01T10:36:37.868\", \"fieldxxxxxUUUU\": {\"sssssssCCCCCCCCCGGGG\": \"xxxxb039-fe1c-4d14-acb8-82ff80912869\", \"xxxxxxxxxxxOOOGGGG\": \"xxxx22d4-3327-35b0-92eb-1784308d718d\", \"ccccccccccUUUUII\": \"xxxx9be3-b728-43cb-8cc2-558eb872af22\", \"field\": \"2021-11-01\", \"fie\": \"2022-04-30\"}, \"fieldgggg\": {\"id\": \"xxxxb3ca-7846-3104-8c4d-feb016a9e618\", \"name\": \"default\", \"states\": [{\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-01\", ,\
 "fie\": \"2021-11-02\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldaaaa\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-10-30\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-02\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-03\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldaaaa\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-10-31\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-03\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-04\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"available\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-01\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-04\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-05\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-02\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-05\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-06\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"
 a
 vailable\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-03\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-06\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-07\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-04\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-07\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-08\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-05\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-08\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-09\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-06\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-09\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-10\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\":
 
 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-07\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-10\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-11\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-08\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-11\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-12\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-09\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-12\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-13\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-10\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-13\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-14\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false,
 \
 "fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-11\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-14\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-15\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-12\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-15\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-16\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-13\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-16\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-17\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-11-14\"}, {\"validity\": {\"field\": \"2021-11-17\", \"fie\": \"2021-11-18\"}, \"fieldxxx\": 10, \"fieldyyyy\": 10, \"fieldzzzz\": 0, \"fieldq\": 0, \"fieldbbb\": true, \"fieldssss\": false, \"fieldYYY\": false, \"fieldfield\": \"2021-1
 1
```

The problem is that a response contains redundant new lines.

It looks fine for gmail (email and email-json) and sqs notifications.

Any ideas ?